# How Can I add A delete button in chooser Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an activity that include an Imageview, when clicked this Image view, this chooser start to set image in Image view. It works well but I want to add delete button to this chooser intent  
for example, if Imageview in the activity has an image, I want to delete that image from this chooser by delete button 
[image]

and also this is my codes for this chooser(this codes is part of my activity) :

```
 final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.select_source));

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_DATA_REMOVED,del);
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 12312);
```

would you please help me to add a delete button for deleting image from imageview in this chooser?

Comment: I don't think you can. One way I would suggest is to first ask the user for camera, gallery and delete option on user tap and when user click on camera/gallery option then show these apps which can handle that intent

Comment: you can not do that because it have wrong logic, no API or function support you send command to delete a image in gallery from intent instead to delete a image you should get uri (or real path) of image after that you can use File.Delete() or Uri to delete any file in local/extarnal storage

Comment: or you can delete any media file through Uri from my comment above by call context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);

Comment: @VivekMishra but how can  whatsApp do that?

Comment: @GiapLee I want just set a button in this chooser, when the user press the button, I can handle the deleting

Comment: http://pilcrowpipe.blogspot.in/2012/01/creating-custom-android-intent-chooser.html . This link shows how to create a custom intent chooser. Check it may be you can do that with it. I have not tried making it but it may help

Comment: oh. now i see. And now you only do that with custom intent chooser: U can  create a gallery your own to list all image.

Comment: I posted a guide that helped me achieve this here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41539606/3243540